# Creating new layer in ArcGIS for Desktop with Python Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-toolbox

I would like to create new shapefile layer or memory layer with one point with certain coordinates in ArcGIS 10.2 with Python Toolbox. Which function should I use? I wrote this code:

```
import arcpy

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Python Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""
        self.tools = [XY]


class XY(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "XY"
        self.description = "Coordinates to point"
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        parameters = []

        x = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="X",
            name="x",
            datatype="String",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
        parameters.append(x)

        y = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Y",
            name="y",
            datatype="String",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")
        parameters.append(y)

        return parameters

    def isLicensed(self):
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        return

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        x = float(parameters[0].valueAsText)
        y = float(parameters[1].valueAsText)
```

Comment: You will need to create a new feature class which you can store in the in_memory geodatabase. http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-feature-class.htm and http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm

Comment: Alternatively you can construct an arcpy.Geometry() and then use Copy Features to copy to the in_memory gdb: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm and http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python Toolbox portion of your code looks fine, it would be better to just focus on your feature class and point creation portion (even if you separate that out from the Python Toolbox to test).

```
def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    x = float(parameters[0].valueAsText)
    y = float(parameters[1].valueAsText)

    # This could be added as another parameter for output file name and path
    outputFile = "n:/gisse/output/pointoutput.shp"  
    # OR
    # outputFile = "in_memory/pointoutput"

    newPoint = arcpy.Point()
    pntGeometry = []
    newPoint.X = x    # Note the upper case X in newPoint.X
    newPoint.Y = y    # Note the upper case Y in newPoint.Y
    pntGeometry.append(arcpy.PointGeometry(newPoint))

    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pntGeometry, outputFile)
```

---

If this is designed to be an in_memory dataset you'll need to also add it to your map

```
layer_name = "newPoint"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(outputFile, layer_name)

add_layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer_name)

arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, add_layer)
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```